# convert nested loops to recursive

Tags: c, loops, recursion, tree

i want to create a minimax tree which has 9 depth. I used 9 nested loop and too many        variable. Now i want to convert this loops to recursive. Thank you for answers. This my code.

```
int a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h;
for(a=0;a<9;a++) 
{
  y=y->branch[a];
  yap(y,8);           
  for(b=0;b<8;b++) 
  {
    y=y->branch[b];
    yap(y,7);                            
    for(c=0;c<7;c++) 
    {         
      y=y->branch[c];
      yap(y,6);                 
      for(d=0;d<6;d++) 
      {
        y=y->branch[d];
        yap(y,5);                        
        for(e=0;e<5;e++) 
        {                 
          y=y->branch[e];
          yap(y,4);                 
          for(f=0;f<4;f++) 
          {
            y=y->branch[f];
            yap(y,3);
            for(g=0;g<3;g++) 
            {
              y=y->branch[g];
              yap(y,2);
              for(h=0;h<2;h++) 
              {
                y=y->brancg[h];
                yap(y,1);         
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Would you mind to indent it, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void recursive(int max)
{
    int a;
    for(a=0;a<max;a++) 
    {
        y=y->branch[a];
        yap(y,max - 1);
        if (max > 2) 
            recursive(max - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Though I didn't really think it was necessary because none of the other variables where declared besides the ints, in the code snippet in the question.

Comment: As it appears to be a learner's question, specificity that your experience may not need is typically warranted here.  Interesting that OP and you use a _global `y`.  Wonder how to do this with a local one: `recursive()` may need to pass and return `y`.  Hmmmm.  But its Friday night...